# Java Explicit Reference Casting

Tags: java

How come there is no compiler error casting Number to List? I thought the types had to be relate.

```
Number k = 10;
List m = new ArrayList();
m = (List)k;
```

Comment: Your Number class, is from java.lang package?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just a guess but I think it's got something to do with `m` being an interface reference.  If you change it to `ArrayList m = new ArrayList();`, it shows a compile time error.

> I thought the types had to be relate.

Number is a class(abstract) and List is an interface so they can be related through another class.

so technically you could have

```
class Foo extends Number implements List
{
   ... 
}
```

and

```
    Number k = ... ; // 
    List m = new Foo();
    m = (List) k;
```

could be legal and will run without exception if k is pointing to a type compatible with `Foo`.

So if you refer to an object by an interface, resolution is deferred till runtime.

Comment: should it be `class MyFooImpl extends MyFoo{ }` instead of `class MyFooImpl{ }` ? Anyways, all of the compile time errors are where the assignment is to a class type reference.

Comment: Given the following:

`interface Foo { }
abstract class MyFoo implements Foo { }
class MyFooImpl extends MyFoo { }`

Results:

`Foo f1 = new MyFooImpl();
MyFoo f2 = new MyFooImpl();
MyFooImpl f3 = new MyFooImpl();
List m1 = new ArrayList();
ArrayList m2 = new ArrayList();

f1 = (Foo)m1;
f1 = (Foo)m2;
  
f2 = (MyFoo)m1;
f2 = (MyFoo)m2; // ERROR
  
f3 = (Foo)m1; // ERROR
f3 = (MyFooImpl)m1;
f3 = (MyFooImpl)m2; // ERROR
  
m1 = (List)f1;
m1 = (List)f2;
m1 = (List)f3;
m1 = (ArrayList)f1;
  
m2 = (List)f1; // ERROR
m2 = (ArrayList)f1;
m2 = (ArrayList)f2; // ERROR
m2 = (ArrayList)f3; // ERROR`